# Android how to share custom objects instance in the application

Tags: android

I have created an application which uses a lot of custom objects I've created to manage parts of the application.

for example:

- FacebookManager class - responsible for connecting to facebook
- DatabaseManager class - responsible for application's database connection
- etc...

these classes must be reachable for all application's classes.

i've extend the Application class and i'm sharing the Application instance between class so every class will be able to reach the global objects (and some more methods).
i'm wondering if this is the correct way of doing what i want, or should i create a class with static methods for the same propose.

I've read a lot about it and understood that from the memory point of view - non of these ways are best.

is there a way to save an object to the SharedPereferences and get it from another class ?
or any other idea ?

Comment: You could look at trying a singleton class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your classes contain no states but only utility methods - you can arrange them as Utils classes, with no constructors and static methods. Otherwise, take a look at the [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which is used to create a global access point for an object of class and ensures there's only one object of that class in the whole system. Hope this helps.

Comment: what is better ? a Utils class or Application class extension

Comment: @AsafNevo, I won't recommend to extend Application in this case.

Comment: @AsafNevo, From the design point of view, your Singletons will be more reusable if you don't tie them to the Application interface.

Comment: @AsafNevo, Anyway, based on your description, you want to have at least two global classes. How will you manage to have two Application extending classes in a single Application?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27002/discussion-between-egor-and-asaf-nevo)